# Import Filemaker database into 3rd party database

Tags: odbc, filemaker

Can we use filemaker database into any 3rd party database provider(MySQL,SQL) ?
If yes , how to use this ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many options here.

• Sync data between FileMaker and another SQL database using [360Works MirrorSync](http://mirrorsync.com) (I am one of the authors).

• Push data to the SQL database from FileMaker using a scheduled / triggered script combined with ODBC or JDBC calls. (I also wrote a [JDBC plugin](http://360works.com/jdbc-plugin/) for FileMaker, don't mean to sound like an advertisement here).

• Use ESS in FileMaker, which stores your FileMaker in some other SQL databases. Might require some major restructuring of an existing database.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Sam's answer:

If it is one off import, you can use csv or tab separated export from FileMaker and import to the target db.

You can also export xml and use XSLT if you need a particular format.